# SQL Server : matching columns with same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Match the columns with name, if first table has two same name (Test) and second table has three same name (Test) means first table 3rd should be empty and second table 3rd row should 'Test'.

```
create table #tmp1
( 
     name varchar(100),
     price decimal(10, 2)
)

insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 200.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 100.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test1', 500.00)
insert into #tmp1 values('Test1', 300.00)

create table #tmp
(
     name varchar(100),
     price decimal(10,2)
)

insert into #tmp values('Test', 200.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test', 300.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test', 400.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test1', 300.00)
insert into #tmp values('Test3', 300.00)
```

Expected output

```
Name  price  Name Price
Test  200.00 Test  200.00
Test  100.00 Test  300.00
             Test  400.00
Test1 300.00 Test1 300.00
Test1 500.00
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sql server is used

Comment: The output should also show a `Test3   300` entry if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking to do a full outer join.

```
SELECT TMP1.NAME NAME1, TMP1.PRICE PRICE1, TMP.NAME, TMP.PRICE INTO COMMON_TMP
FROM TMP1 INNER JOIN TMP 
ON TMP1.NAME = TMP.NAME AND TMP1.PRICE = TMP.PRICE;

SELECT * FROM COMMON_TMP
UNION ALL
SELECT A.NAME AS NAME1, A.PRICE AS PRICE1, B.NAME, B.PRICE
FROM
    (SELECT TMP1.NAME, TMP1.PRICE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TMP1.NAME ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNUM FROM TMP1 LEFT JOIN COMMON_TMP C ON TMP1.NAME = C.NAME AND TMP1.PRICE = C.PRICE WHERE C.NAME IS NULL OR C.PRICE IS NULL) A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TMP.NAME, TMP.PRICE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TMP.NAME ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNUM FROM TMP LEFT JOIN COMMON_TMP C ON TMP.NAME = C.NAME AND TMP.PRICE = C.PRICE WHERE C.NAME IS NULL OR C.PRICE IS NULL) B
    ON A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.RNUM = B.RNUM
    WHERE (B.NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TMP1.NAME FROM TMP1 INNER JOIN TMP ON TMP1.NAME = TMP.NAME) OR B.NAME IS NULL)
    AND (A.NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TMP1.NAME FROM TMP1 INNER JOIN TMP ON TMP1.NAME = TMP.NAME) OR A.NAME IS NULL)
ORDER BY NAME1, PRICE;
```

Comment: but i don't want Test3 record because first table does not contain 'Test3'

Comment: i want to show like same drug name with different price. In second table Test is missing

Comment: Please mention these conditions in your post.

Comment: I believe this solution does not return expected output: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=32c4b93d3131ed427ad4575dc25abf90

Comment: Of course it won't. Just got to know some new conditions that OP is looking to have incorporated.

Comment: the same expected output is there from the beginning and your solution is returning something different (see the link provided)

Comment: Test 400 is missing.

Comment: What if the `#tmp` table has two entries for `Test    200` values and `#tmp1` table has one entry for `Test   200` value?`

Comment: i have drug name and price list for every month. Need to compare two months(current month and previous month).May be price change two times  in a month. That's why i entered two test names

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` and `full join`

```
select t1.name, t1.price,
       t2.name, t2.price
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by price) rn
  from #tmp1 t1
  where exists(select 1 from #tmp t2 where t1.name = t2.name)
) t1
full join (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by price) rn
  from #tmp t1
  where exists(select 1 from #tmp1 t2 where t1.name = t2.name)  
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Exists is used to eliminate results without proper mirror in the second table

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e5c9d44a90977aef66f2a19d691d50b0)

Comment: but both columns present in two tables. Test3 not present in first table

Comment: output should be 1.)Test 200.00 Test 200.00  2.)Test 100.00 Test 300.00. Price same means give first priority to match

Comment: i have drug name and price list for every month. Need to compare two months(current month and previous month).1. if drugname is matched and price is not matched then i need to show the records. 2. if drugname is present one time in previous month but two times present in current month then i need to show the records.

Comment: For same drugname, price is changed more than one time in a month

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    create table #tmp1
    ( 
            name varchar(100),
            price decimal(10, 2)
    )

    insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 200.00)
    insert into #tmp1 values('Test', 100.00)
    insert into #tmp1 values('Test1', 500.00)
    insert into #tmp1 values('Test1', 300.00)

    create table #tmp
    (
            name varchar(100),
            price decimal(10,2)
    )

    insert into #tmp values('Test', 200.00)
    insert into #tmp values('Test', 300.00)
    insert into #tmp values('Test', 400.00)
    insert into #tmp values('Test1', 300.00)
    insert into #tmp values('Test3', 300.00)

    ;with cte1
    As(
        select Row_Number() OVer(Partition by name order by name ,price) rn1 ,* from #tmp1
    )


    ,

    cte2
    As(
        select Row_Number() OVer(Partition by name order by name,price ) rn2 ,* from #tmp
    )


        SELECT c1.Name,c1.price,c2.Name,c2.price
        FROM cte1 c1 
        FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.rn1 = c2.rn2 and c1.Name=c2.Name 
        WHERE (c2.Name in (Select name from cte1) or c1.Name in (Select name from cte2))
        order by ISNULL(c1.Name,c2.Name)




    Drop table #tmp1
    Drop table #tmp
```